# Wordpress gives 404 in any page with any kind of permalink, but when I change the theme it works. How to fix?

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress theme that has the page.php, but it gives 404 in any page that I create, even using the plain permalink (http://localhost:8080/?page_id=33141).

But when I change to wordpress theme the page works.

I think it is not about htacces, because none of the themes should work.

Could the theme redirect all pages to 404? I didn't find anything in the code.

Could someone refresh my mind?

Thanks.

I am running it in a docker container but I dont think it has influence because the other theme works.

Comment: In my opinion, the issue seems to be theme related. I dealt with a similar issue recently myself where all the pages weren't showing because the theme was a custom build and was using the outdated code. However, after changing the theme and reverting back to the WordPress default it worked. Which seems to me like what you have described.

Can you name me the theme that you are using and have fiddled around with changing the version of PHP to an older one if you really want to continue on using this theme? Which in my opinion would not be the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try go to setting->permalink and click save and clear cache and fresh page.

Comment: I did all that and deactivated all plugins, same thing.

Answer (score 0):

go to settings-> permalinks and save the permalinks and also clear the cache. sometime it is occurring due to cache.

And also sometimes it may happens due to permission is declined from cpanel

Go to cpanel and then right click select permission and change the permission. It may be helpful